# Needing to submit form twice to post correctly using jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form using jQuery AJAX.  I'm not so great with this code, so am not able to see

> **Issue** - why I need to submit the form twice in order for it to post.

When I submit the form the textarea clear back to `placeholder` text and nothing happens.  When I click it again, the post submits and displays.  I have the following `textarea` and `button`

```
<textarea class="add-message-textarea" name="message_body" id="message_textarea" placeholder="Write message"></textarea>
<button class="post-button button" type="submit" name="post_message" id="message_submit">Post</button>
```

When I submit I have the following:

```
$body = '';
if(isset($_POST['post_message'])) {

    if(isset($_POST['message_body'])) {
        $body = $_POST['message_body'];
    }
}
```

Then AJAX call:

```
var userLoggedIn = '<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>';
var user_to      = '<?php echo $user_to; ?>';
var body         = '<?php echo $body; ?>'
// var body          = $("#message_textarea").val();

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#message_submit").click(function(){

    //ajax request for send 'sending a new message' string to dB
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/handlers/ajax_send_message.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'userLoggedIn':userLoggedIn, 'user_to':user_to, 'body':body},
        cache: true,

                success: function(response) {
                  console.log("message_sent");
                }

        }); 
    });
});
```

`ajax_send_message.php` looks like this simple:

```
global $con;
if(isset($_POST['userLoggedIn']) && isset($_POST['user_to']) && isset($_POST['body'])) {

    $userLoggedIn = $_POST['userLoggedIn'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $user_to = $_POST['user_to'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


        $message_obj = new Message($con, $userLoggedIn);
        $message_obj->sendMessage($user_to, $body, $date);
}
```

I'm able to get this to work no problem using PHP with the below but I don't want the page to reload.

```
if(isset($_POST['post_message'])) {

    if(isset($_POST['message_body'])) {
        $body = $_POST['message_body'];
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $message_obj->sendMessage($user_to, $body, $date);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have a form whose processor returns a new page that contains the AJAX call and sets the `body` JavaScript variable. Clicking on the form in the new page performs the AJAX request.

Comment: @Barmar.  Yes I see, but when I set the action to `<form action="messages.php?u=<?php echo $user_to; ?>" method="POST">` the button does nothing.  Right now `action=""`

Comment: `user_to` is declared from URL - `$user_to = $_GET['u'];`

Comment: I think the idea is that you don't need to submit the form directly *and* use AJAX. One or the other seems sufficient.

Comment: @showdev so I would declare body like `var body = $("#message_textarea").val();` and eliminate the php?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Define the `body` variable inside your `click` handler (or a `submit` handler, as [mentioned by Ali Sheikhpour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54952748/924299)). That will pull the value from your form element. Then you can pass it to your PHP script using AJAX.

Comment: Looks like an incomprehension about [server-side and client-side](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming).

Comment: Worked.  I needed to define `var body = $("#message_textarea").val();` inside the `click` handler.  Cut the php & it submits on the first go.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to submit a form but prevent reloading the page, you just need to return `false` from clicking submit button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#message_submit").click(function(){
   //ajax request for send 'sending a new message' string to dB
    $.ajax({
    url: "includes/handlers/ajax_send_message.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {'userLoggedIn':userLoggedIn, 'user_to':user_to, 'body':body},
    cache: true,
    success: function(response) {
          console.log("message_sent");
         }

    });

    return false;

    });
});
```

Note: If you want to totally prevent a form to be submitted, attach the event listener to the form submission not on clicking the button. User may submit the form by pressing `Enter` or other unpredictable actions attached to the device keybord etc.

```
$(YOUR_FORM).on("submit",function(){
  //Ajax code here
  return false;
})
```

Comment: I agree with your advice about using the `submit` event. I just want to note that the `body` variable should be defined before passing it to the PHP script. In the OP's code, that variable is defined from `$_POST`, but it should be defined from within the JavaScript code instead. I think that's the crux of the OP's issue.

Comment: I need to define `var body = $("#message_textarea").val();` inside the click handler.  But I'm going to try the `submit` event.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you don't prevent your form from submitting.
You can do this by: `e.preventDefault()` in `.submit(function(e){})` callback function

```js
$("#reg").submit(function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reg">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="Rick">
  <input type="text" name="last_name" value="Astley">
  <input type="submit">
<form>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried this.  I understand what you're saying, prevent the form processor from submitting initially and have the form submit onclick with JQuery.  It just makes the button dead however.